# Has_many in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many, formtastic

I'd like to generate 3 associated forms for record using has_many. It should be 3 forms, not less not more. Is it possible to do using formtastic's has_many? I made it with javascript but it looks like not the best approach for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `>= v0.6.2`, you can turn off the "Add New *" by passing the option `new_record: false` on the `f.has_many` fieldset.

```
f.has_many :children, new_record: false do |child_f|
```

You can also override your resource building method to create three of your child models:

```
controller do
  def build_new_resource
    res = super
    3.times { res.children.build }
  end
end
```

This should give you a new model with the correct number of nested forms, and will keep the form from letting the user add extra fields.